# How to solve Uncontrolled Component problem in React with Function Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I was making Form components.(It is Function Component)
It is Uncontrolled Component, because I don't want unnecessary render in `Input` components.
But it has unexpected word.

1. I try to set value with `setState()` in `Input` Component and get through value props `onChange`. It is not pass whole value from `Input` to `Form`
2. I don't want unnecessary rendering. However, when I enter value in email, react rendering with password at the same time.

How can I solve this problem?

Code Sand Box Link
https://codesandbox.io/s/makewelldonecomponents-txxl0?file=/src/Input.js

or Code

(Input Component)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Input = ({ type, placeholder, onChange }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  function handleChange(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
    onChange(value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {console.log("render", placeholder)}
      <input placeholder={placeholder} value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

(Form Compoenent)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Input from "./Input";

const Form = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(email, password);
  }

  function handleEmail(value) {
    setEmail(value);
    console.log(value);
  }

  function handlePassword(value) {
    setPassword(value);
  }

  function handleReset(e) {
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
    setState(state + 1);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Input
        key={state + "email"}
        type="email"
        placeholder="이메일"
        onChange={handleEmail}
      />
      <Input
        key={state + "password"}
        type="password"
        placeholder="비밀번호"
        onChange={handlePassword}
      />
      <button type="submit">가입</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleReset}>
        초기화
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use `useRef` instead of `useState` in `Input` Component.

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const Input = ({ type, placeholder, onChange }) => {
  const valRef = useRef("");

  function handleChange(e) {
    valRef.current = e.target.value;
    onChange(valRef.current);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {console.log("render", placeholder)}
      <input
        placeholder={placeholder}
        value={valRef.current}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

2. use `useCallback` to `handleEmail`, `handlePassword` functions

```js
  const handleEmail = useCallback((value) => {
    setEmail(value);
    console.log(value);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more question. When I render component at the first time, useCallback did render just one time. right? 
So, you answer Q2. but, I rewrite my code with useCallback still unnecessary rendering in handleEmail, handlePassword.  
Is it inevitable work?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an uncontrolled form in React without using state and multiple change handlers.

Here's the updated sandbox:

[image: Edit makeWellDoneComponents (forked)]

`Form` component:

```
const Form = () => {
  const email = useRef(null);
  const password = useRef(null);

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(email.current.value, password.current.value);
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Input type="email" placeholder="이메일" ref={email} />
      <Input type="password" placeholder="비밀번호" ref={password} />
      <button type="submit">가입</button>
      <button type="reset">초기화</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

`Input` component:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";

const Input = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <input {...props} ref={ref} />;
});
```

Comment: Good Answer. However, I need to know about Q2. How to know render only one component when I typed in email or password?

Comment: @Aaaaaa In the above implementation, none of the input components are rerendered when entering email/password